# US Customs Fingerprinting identification

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Can the customs officers pick up your name change at the port via your fingerprints or photo in Hawaii?

Comment: Yes? Why wouldn't they?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Certainly, if you've given your biometrics under one name and and then show up with a different name, both names will map back to you in the system. This is [quite common](http://www.nextgov.com/defense/2012/08/fingerprint-records-reveal-825000-immigrants-multiple-names-inconsistent-birth-dates/57620/) though, as many people change their name. It would help if you gave the full details of the situation and why you're asking.

Comment: My son at 15 was turned back at lax for dual intent.  I was totally unfamiliar with us immigration and went on the trip with encouragement from friends in the hs to let him come and experience high school there. Never again. I was complacent and foolish and thought it ok to travel on the ESTA. Long story short we were detained and"turned back"not "deported" and were told by the officers we were free to travel back if we wished.

Comment: Never again. I was complacent and foolish and thought it ok to travel on the ESTA. Long story short we were detained and"turned back"not "deported" and were told by the officers we were free to travel back if we wished. I took it as gospel. That was 2014. Last week i applied for his ESTA for my son to travel to Hawaii and thanks to my naievety i was honest and ticked yes for the deportation question.

Comment: Of course his travel wasn't authorised and now I'm scrambling to find any way to get him there as his bball tournament starts next Tuesday and we were advised that maybe anew passport with a name change will help him get that ESTA.

Comment: Now i don't want him to go as this long winded story will just look like a lot of hot air to a customs/immigration officer. He is booked to go for 10 days max.  Now i don't want him to go as this long winded story will just look like a lot of hot air to a customs/immigration officer. He is booked to go for 10 days max.

Comment: Do not try to fool them with a new name / passport! That will backfire. You can try to apply for a new ESTA, answer all the questions **correctly, including the one were you were asked about previous refusals**. If ESTA is refused, which is a chance, apply for a visa. Let me repeat this, if you are caught lying to them (which you would want to do via a name change), you are in deep trouble and can forhet any travels to the U.S. any time soon or ever!

Comment: I am also voting to close this question as unclear until you edit your question to include the details you added in comments in a concise manner (even with the comments I still don't understand everything) and include your nationality and how the name change came about.

Comment: Name change is a simple process... he's aussie born i'm a nz citizen. The nz passport office did it all in conjunction with their births deaths n marriagrs office. He was going to travel with both passports nd explain when he hot to the port but i suppose thats completely foolish as well.thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are still a number of details missing, but you've given enough information to have a decent sense of your question. In short: **do not do this**.

As I understand your question, your son was previously refused entry to the United States (not deported) and now wants to visit. The ESTA form asks about previous refusals, you honestly and accurately checked yes, the ESTA was not authorized, and you now want to come up with a way to lie about it in the hope of working around this problem.

This doesn't work. Everything about US immigration law applies to him as an individual person, not simply to one of his names or passports. Here's what Customs and Border Protection [has to say](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1097/~/previously-denied-a-visa-or-immigration-benefit) about this plan (emphasis addded):

> If you were previously denied a visa, or previously refused entry to
>   the United States, or previously removed from the U.S., your ESTA
>   application will most likely be denied.
>
> If you were allowed to board your carrier, you may be subject to
>   additional processing upon arrival at U.S. ports of entry, and may be
>   denied admission to the U.S. **Applicants who are uncertain of whether
>   they qualify for travel under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) are
>   encouraged to apply for ESTA authorization early, to allow time to
>   apply for a visa, if needed.**
>
> Many people make the mistake of thinking that if they were denied a
>   visa when they were a citizen of one country, then become a citizen of
>   another country, they can travel to the U.S. under the visa waiver
>   program using their new passport. That is wrong. The eligibility
>   question about having been denied a visa does not ask whether or not
>   the denial was made after you became a citizen of another country. It
>   asks, "Have you ever been denied a visa?" - period. If you answer "No"
>   then we determine that you have been denied a visa in the past, we
>   consider that to be fraud, and you will be barred from entry for a
>   number of years. **It is better to admit the truth, and then apply for a
>   visa, than go through the experience of being deported for fraud.**

TL;DR: your plan amounts to fraud and could attract a lengthy ban from the United States.

Your son now needs to apply for a visa at the US Consulate serving your area. Many people who are refused ESTAs do successfully receive a US visa and are able to travel, especially if they can demonstrate strong ties that ensure they will return home. Unfortunately, it may well too late to receive one by Tuesday. It's certainly worth contacting them in the hope they can work some magic, but the process usually takes more than a couple days. I know that's not the answer you or your son want to hear, and I'm sorry for that.